# Unbalanced forces on an Engine

Tags: mechanical-engineering, vibration

so I have a 4 Cylinder inline engine configuration.

How would I identify the speeds at which vibrations due to unbalanced forces are acting?

I have data such as RPM and Force and Moments acting

Comment: 4 cyl are always out of balance, 6 cyl inline are much smoother for a reason. Always covered in mechanical textbooks on balancing.

Comment: "*How would I identify when the speeds due to unbalanced forces are acting?*" I think that sentence needs a re-write. Speeds don't act.